# how to inherit field value from one module to another module?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

I want to inherit the value of amount_total from accounts module to my custom module. amount_total is a field in accounts module, so how can I retrieve it's value in my custom module. I  have already set dependency on account in my **openerp** file. But still in eclipse it says as undefined variable:amount_total

custom.py ,

```
class account_invoice(models.Model):

  _inherit = "account.invoice"  

  print amount_total
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use ***self.amount_total***. form inside a method. like:

```
@api.one
def print_amount(self):
    print self.amount_total
```

Comment: api.one is depreciated so use api.multi